# How to change : Fullcalendar generates GET request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get, fullcalendar

I am implementing fullcalendar on my website.

I have created a div with calendar as id.

I have put data from a SQL query in a php variable and used json encode to get the right format.

This is how I create the calendar :

```
$html .= "<script src='/wp-content/plugins/biobelt/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script src='/wp-content/plugins/biobelt/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
        <link rel= 'stylesheet' href='/wp-content/plugins/biobelt/fullcalendar.css' type='text/css'>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var bevents = '".$buildingevents."'
                console.log(bevents)
                jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    defaultDate: '" . $_SESSION['statDateFrom'] ."',
                    editable: true,
                    events: bevents,
                });
            });
        </script>";
```

The console log gives me an output of the array that I am passing to events, and it is the correct format :

```
[{"id":"1","titre":"1","start":"2018-04-09 07:00:01","stop":"2018-04-09 11:00:00"},{"id":"2","titre":"1","start":"2018-04-09 07:00:01","stop":"2018-04-09 11:00:00"},{"id":"3","titre":"2","start":"2018-04-09 16:00:01","stop":"2018-04-09 21:00:00"},{"id":"4","titre":"2","start":"2018-04-09 16:00:01","stop":"2018-04-09 21:00:00"}, etc...
```

What I get from this is :
GET 403 Forbidden Error

I checked in apache logs, this is because the URL is too long since every field of the array is put into the url.
For some reason I don't want to change the limit request line in apache conf file.
I want to generate a POST instead of GET request.
And I would like to know how it generates a GET request since I didn't put GET anywhere in my files.

**EDIT :**
according to : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed
Fullcalendar create the get request and the URL. The problem persists since the URL is too long and I want to create a POST request instead. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the documentation somewhat.

You said

> The console log gives me an output of the array that I am passing to events, and it is the correct format

And indeed what you've showed does look like a Javascript array. So...it's a static array and *not* a URL. You do not have any kind of server endpoint to which you can make a separate ajax call to get your events. Therefore the article you linked to (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) is not relevant. Instead you are providing a static list of events as per the method described at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array).

Except that...you're not. Due to the way you've written your code, you're providing a *string* instead of an array. That is causing fullCalendar to assume you're providing a URL, and then trying to call that URL, and it's no surprise that it errors.

If you simply remove the single quotes from

```
var bevents = '".$buildingevents."'
```

so that it becomes

```
var bevents = ".$buildingevents.";
```

then your code should work ok, because this will inject a hard-coded array into the JavaScript instead of a string.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Great explanations